# IMSBuildNuGetProjectSystem implementation

Tags: c#, nuget

I am trying to update nuget packages using NuGet.ProjectManagement
To call update method I need to create instance of MSBuildNuGetProject but I cannot because I cannot find IMSBuildNuGetProjectSystem implementation.

Does somebody know where to find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of implementing own class I have used implementation from Nuget.exe.
I have installed the NuGet.CommandLine package and manually added a reference to Nuget.exe

Answer (score 0):

You will need to write your own class that implements the IMSBuildNuGetProjectSystem interface.

If you look at the source code you can see a [VSMSBuildNuGetProjectSystem](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Client/blob/65c0ee72cc18c694b46ab2d11b372b74bde169be/src/NuGet.Clients/PackageManagement.VisualStudio/ProjectSystems/VSMSBuildNuGetProjectSystem.cs) class that is implemented for Visual Studio.